# Angular 8 routerLinkActive with params

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I have two tabs on my sidebar, one for `Open chats`, one for `Closed chats`. When I select the `Open chats` tab, it becomes bold. When I selected the `Closed chats` tab, both tabs become bold. If I add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` to the `a` tag of `Open chats` it fixes the problem, but it opens up a new problem. When I select a chat within the `Open chats` component, the url switched to `.com/messenger/{randomString}` the `Open chats` tab stays bold which is good, but when I refresh the page and the url stays, the `Open chats` tab is no longer bold/active. How would I accomplish both keeping the `messenger/complete` and `messenger` separate, while still allowing `messenger` and `messenger/:id` to stay active together.

Note: I technically also need `messenger/complete` and `messenger/complete/:id` to stay active together in the same way

`sidebar html`

```
      <a class="inboxLabel openChatsLabel" routerLink="/messenger" routerLinkActive="selectedLabel selectedOpen">
        <div></div>
        <p>Open Chats</p>
      </a>
      <a class="inboxLabel closedChatsLabel" routerLink="/messenger/complete"
        routerLinkActive="selectedLabel selectedClosed">
        <div></div>
        <p>Closed Chats</p>
      </a>
```

`routing module`

```
  {
    path: 'messenger',
    component: OverviewComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'messenger/:id',
    component: OverviewComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'messenger/complete/:id',
    component: OverviewComponent,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out!

`sidebar ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css'],
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  completeTab: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.completeTab = event.url.includes('/complete') ? true : false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`sidebar html`

```
  <a class="inboxLabel openChatsLabel" routerLink="/messenger" routerLinkActive="selectedLabel selectedOpen"
        [ngClass]="{'selectedLabel': !this.completeTab, 'selectedOpen' : !this.completeTab}">
        <div></div>
        <p>Open Chats</p>
      </a>
      <a class="inboxLabel closedChatsLabel" routerLink="/messenger/complete"
        routerLinkActive="selectedLabel selectedClosed">
        <div></div>
        <p>Closed Chats</p>
      </a>
```